# dask persist behavior inconsistent

Tags: python, python-3.x, dask, dask-distributed

I found weird behavior with dask persist, if I comment out this line

```py
# client = Client(memory_limit='20GB',n_workers=1)  # Connect to distributed cluster and override default
```

and perform

```py
dd_feature_009a013a_normalized_noneedshift = dd_feature_009a013a_normalized_noneedshift.head(1000000,compute=False).persist()
```

persist operates as expected.. computed and store in memory allowing me to access result instantaneously
However, if I uncomment

```py
client = Client(memory_limit='20GB',n_workers=1)  # Connect to distributed cluster and override default
```

Then

```py
dd_feature_009a013a_normalized_noneedshift = dd_feature_009a013a_normalized_noneedshift.head(1000000,compute=False).persist()
dd_feature_009a013a_normalized_noneedshift = client.persist(dd_feature_009a013a_normalized_noneedshift)
```

is not doing anything. Lazy dataframe is returned immediately... What shall I do to achieve the same behavior when I turn on `client = Client(memory_limit='20GB',n_workers=1)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we persist an object with `client.persist`, we get back a future, that refers to the results of the computation. Once computed, the result will be stored on a worker or multiple workers, as appropriate. Running `client.persist` on an existing future will give back another future... so a reference to a reference to another computation, which is likely unnecessary.

To get the result of a future, one can run `.result()` on the future itself. This will block further commands until the future is computed and the results are returned.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. So in order to actually persist it, shall i do `ddf.result()` or `ddf=ddf.result()`? i want to keep `ddf` type as Dask Dataframe, but i want its content to be persisted like previously without client.

Comment: You are welcome, kindly note that `ddf=ddf.result()` will convert the dataframe into pandas, bring into memory and overwrite the dask dataframe (`ddf`). You might want to use: `fut_ddf = client.persist(ddf)` for persisting and then run `fut_ddf.result()` to load the result into memory...  (it's not necessary to name it as `fut_ddf`, it's possible to also save it as `ddf`, but just wanted to avoid potential confusion)